# ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native, ionic-view

how do i order it to display this array in the dropdown??

[image]

my.html

```
<ion-item>
    <img src="assets/img/travel/city.png" width="25" height="30" item-start>
    <ion-label stacked>Pilih Kota</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="shuttledestination2" name="shuttledestination2" interface="action-sheet">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let data of traveldest" value="{{ data.id }}"><b>{{ data.label }}</b></ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Whats the type of `traveldest` here?

Comment: @Dhy46 you data seems in **object** format, not an **array** format??

Comment: @eduPeeth traveldest: any = [];

Comment: @Sanoj_V  I do not know I just get that data, i do not know in ionic v2 what's the problem because if i try with ionic v1 data it can appear in the dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `traveldest` clearly is an object of objects and not an arry, you can see by the image where the second line you have `{1{...}, 2{...}, 3{...}}`.

That you need to do is convert this object to an array before assigning it to `traveldest`, you can easy do this by using `Object.values(yourObject)`, so you can do this:

```
this.traveldest = Object.values(yourReceivedObject);
```

`yourReceivedObject` is the response from your HTTP call or anything that is returning your results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: save my day !!!