# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

i want to render the list of users using the `ngFor` directive, but when i try to do this console is showing the error that.

### Error

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

### Group-component.ts

```
groupUsers: any[] = [];

this.groupService.getGroupUsers(this.groupId)
  .subscribe(groupUsers => {
    this.groupUsers = groupUsers;
  });
```

### Group-service.ts

```
getGroupUsers(groupId: number): Observable<any[]> {
      return this.http.get<any[]>(this.baseUrl + 'GroupAttendance/GroupUsers/' + groupId);
}
```

### Group-component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of groupUsers" class="modal-body">
  <div class="card">
   <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>{{ user.user.knownAs }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the response getting the data from the server
[image]

I don't know why console show me this error

Comment: Did you check if you're getting any data from request?

Comment: yes, data is in array format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In your group.component.html

```
   <div *ngIf="groupUsers?.length > 0">
    <div *ngFor="let user of groupUsers" class="modal-body">
      <div class="card">
       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <p>{{ user.user.knownAs }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Hope this will help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/51286078/5114465

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Actually data of array is not ready to serve in html. That's why it is throwing this error. Before showing the data in html file, make sure it is ready to render. You can check it by the following way.

> *ngIf="groupUsers?.length > 0" // Check that **groupUsers** have data and its contains data

.

```
<div *ngIf="groupUsers?.length > 0">

    <div *ngFor="let user of groupUsers" class="modal-body">
      <div class="card">
       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <p>{{ user.user.knownAs }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that groupUsers is not an array. check again your response type.

Did you try to `console.log(groupUsers)` in your subscribe ?

Comment: i check this in console, it is an array

Comment: did you try to add an `*ngIf="groupUsers"` before the loop ?

Comment: Yes my dear, i tried but still the same problem persist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51286078/5114465