# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object] in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

I'm trying to get spotify API from current user's playlists
I have it in my console but I tried to put it into html and i'm getting this error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.
>       at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:4841)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31913)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (PlaylistsComponent.html:2)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45259)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:44637)

Here's my user.service.ts:

```
public getUserPlaylists(): Observable<any> {
  const endpoint = environment.spotifyApi.host + "me/playlists";

  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: `Bearer ${this.accessToken}`,
    }),
  };

  return this.http.get(endpoint, httpOptions);
}
```

Here's my playlists.component.ts:

```
playlists: any;
constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getPlaylists();
}

getPlaylists() {
  let observable = this.userService.getUserPlaylists();
  observable.subscribe((data) => {
    this.playlists = data;
    console.log(this.playlists);
  });
}
```

and here is my html:

```
<div class="playlists text-center">
  <div class="test" *ngFor="let playlist of playlists">
    {{playlist.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Update console from browser:

```
Object
href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/12164174667/playlists?offset=0&limit=20"
items: Array(2)
0: {collaborative: false, description: "", external_urls: {…}, href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/0tNJ7TiGOqqbiFratEY8WD", id: "0tNJ7TiGOqqbiFratEY8WD", …}
1: {collaborative: false, description: "Songs I'm currrently listening to; updated every 2 weeks.", external_urls: {…}, href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/24G8qVxmH4Sg6WfsaRAumW", id: "24G8qVxmH4Sg6WfsaRAumW", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
limit: 20
next: null
offset: 0
previous: null
total: 2
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: `ngFor` expects array, make sure `playlists` is an array. If you want to loop an object then this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51491848/11719787) may help you

Comment: this.playlists = data is the place where error occur. first check the respond that you getting from API. one of that property may contain your playlist as an Array.

Comment: @CodeMind I just added my console print out what i get from the API. May you take a look?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51286078/5114465 check this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can clearly see in the logs that `ngFor` expects Iterables. Instead of assigning full object just assign items

Upate your method like this:

```
getPlaylists() {
 let observable = this.userService.getUserPlaylists();
 observable.subscribe((data) => {
 this.playlists = data.items;
 console.log(this.playlists);
 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you It fixed my problem. But somehow it's not showing all my playlists from spotify...

Comment: Welcome !! That you will need to debug from back end, that what response you are getting back from Spotify API

Comment: really appreciate your help and i jus fixed my back end problem. I wish i can upvote 10 times for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I went through [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/object-model/#playlist-object-simplified) and found what it returns in playlist object. in **external_urls** node you can get required playlist url. then you can iterate **this.playlists**.

```
getPlaylists() {
  let observable = this.userService.getUserPlaylists();
  observable.subscribe((res) => {
    this.playlists = res.external_urls;
    console.log(this.playlists);
  });
}
```